# whitespace aware reading/writing of XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, formatting, whitespace

I need to change some elements of an XML file which are under source control and write the file with no other differences to allow the developers to easily review the changes.

In detail I have a set of elements which need to have an id attribute in the xml code. I find these elements with a xpath expression and add an ID to it. But when the dom is written again, the formatting differs a bit.

1. the order of the attributes is changes to alphabetical
2. the definition of the namespace is moved to the elements (`<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="abc" xmlns:ns2="xzy"><ns2:element/></ns1:root>` changes to `<root xmlns="abc"><element xmlns="xzy"/></root>`)
3. linebreaks and indetion change

The xml is read with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser (namespaceaware: true) and written with javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory (indent: yes).

The best way to preserve the formatting would be to alter the source string, is there a good way to do this without diving in too deep into the xml parsing thing?

Or is there a way to parse the xml to dom whitespace aware?

Answer (score 0):

> the order of the attributes is changes to alphabetical

The order of the attributes is irrelevant as per the spec. If you have built a piece of software that relies on the order of the attributes in an XML file, then that software is broken, plain and easy.

> the definition of the namespace is moved to the elements

That is irrelevant as well.

> linebreaks and indetion change

So is this.

> The best way to preserve the formatting would be to alter the source string,

Absolutely not. Don't do that, that's wrong on every level. XML parsers are complex things because XML parsing is a complex thing. If it was as simple as doing a bunch of string search-and-replace operations, then XML parsers would do that instead of being complex.

---

XML is identical when the DOM it creates is identical. There a countless ways to serialize a DOM. You are at fault if any part of your program relies on the serialized representation of the DOM, instead on the DOM itself.

In any case, most serializers do offer some settings that influence their behavior. If you use the same serializer with the same configuration then you can expect a predictable outcome. That might help a little (i.e. when checking the file into a source control system), but it should not be a reason to start relying on it at the code level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention, that the files are unter source control and it's not the software who relies on the serialized dom but the developers. They should be able to easily review the changes I made to the source code via diff. That's the reason why all the above is relevant in this case.